# Sphinx not return ID from results

Tags: php, linux, sphinx

I have Sphinx running and I can search (YAY), but when I get the results the id for my select isn't there, here is my sphinx.conf:

```
source willem
{
type                            = mysql
sql_host                        = localhost
sql_user                        = root
sql_pass                        = ********
sql_db                          = test
sql_port                        = 3306

sql_query       = SELECT id, question, answer, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) AS date_added FROM faq


sql_attr_timestamp  = date_added

sql_ranged_throttle = 0

# document info query, ONLY for CLI search (ie. testing and debugging)
sql_query_info      = SELECT id, question, answer, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) AS date_added FROM faq WHERE id = $id
}

index willem {
source = willem
path = /home/willem/sphinx
morphology = stem_en
min_word_len = 3
min_prefix_len = 0
}

searchd {
compat_sphinxql_magics = 0
port = 3313
log = /home/willem/searchd.log
query_log = /home/willem/query.log
pid_file = /home/willem/searchd.pid
max_matches = 10000
}
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
$this->load->library('SphinxClient');
    $this->sphinxclient->SetServer('localhost', 3313);
    //$this->sphinxclient->SetLimits(10, 10);
    $this->sphinxclient->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_ANY );
    $this->sphinxclient->SetSortMode( SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE );
    //$this->sphinxclient->SetWeights ( array ( 100, 1 ) );
    $res = $this->sphinxclient->Query('contact', 'willem');
    $error = $this->sphinxclient->GetLastError();
    var_dump($res);var_dump($error);
```

And this is the result:

```
array(10) {
["error"]=>
string(0) ""
["warning"]=>
string(0) ""
["status"]=>
int(0)
["fields"]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(8) "question"
[1]=>
string(6) "answer"
}
["attrs"]=>
array(1) {
["date_added"]=>
int(2)
}
["matches"]=>
array(1) {
[6]=>
array(2) {
  ["weight"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["attrs"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["date_added"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
}
["total"]=>
string(1) "1"
["total_found"]=>
string(1) "1"
["time"]=>
string(5) "0.000"
["words"]=>
array(1) {
["contact"]=>
array(2) {
  ["docs"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["hits"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
}
}
string(0) ""
```

So I get the results, but not the id field, I need it to get the found fields from our database.

Thanks in advance.

PS: first time post, tell me if I did anything wrong or missed another topic answering my question, stackoverflow is the best teacher ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
["matches"]=>
array(1) {
[6]=>
array(2) {
```

Thats the ID right there. The 6 is the id of the document matched.

Can just do

```
$ids = array_keys($res['matches']);
```

to get a array of ids, you can later use.

Comment: See also http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setarrayresult which puts the ID in a differnt place.

Comment: Quick question while this is open, if I want the answer and question field to be return from sphinx query rather than looking it up afterwards in SQL. I am guessing it will be an attribute like the date_created? Is this advisable?

Comment: Yes you would need to set them as an attribute. Can use sql_field_string to make both a field and a string attribute from one column. Beware that attribtes are held in memory by sphinx, so that might be a limitting factor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, our FAQ isn't too big and we have enough Memory on the server. One more question if you don't mind, is there a way to add weight to a row? For example: "where is the duck" is a question asked more often than "what is a duck", but if I search "duck" I want "Where is the duck" to always rank above "What is the duck". Thanks a lot for your help Barryhunter.

Comment: Suggest adding you weight question as a new question. Include more details in the question. What you posted here isnt really clear what is better about one of the rows.